# Reload apache with php automatically

Tags: php, apache, shell, debian, virtualhost

I have an application running where customers can connect their own domain. That is, my customers can log in, enter their domain and a new virtual host is created in the background.

```
shell_exec('cp /var/www/xxxxxxx/storage/app/vhosts/'.$relativeDomain.'.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available');
        shell_exec('rm /var/www/xxxxxxx/storage/app/vhosts/'.$relativeDomain.'.conf');
        shell_exec('chmod 777 /etc/apache2/sites-available/'.$relativeDomain.'.conf');
        shell_exec('a2ensite '.$relativeDomain);
```

The only problem is, as long as Apache is not reloaded, the Virtual Host cannot be applied. Is there any way to execute the command "systemctl reload apache2" via shell script or with the PHP function shell_exec or exec? When i do shell_exec('systemctl reload apache2') nothing happens.

Comment: You probably lack the rights to execute `systemctl` like that, pretty sure this needs `sudo`.

Comment: It's the same. I also tried it with and without sudo. I'm also not really sure if it's even a good idea to reload apache with php. Is there a way to create virtual hosts without having to reload apache?

Comment: You can't just stick `sudo` in there and think you're done, it needs more: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127529 _"I'm also not really sure if it's even a good idea to reload apache with php."_ - probably rather not. _"Is there a way to create virtual hosts without having to reload apache?"_ - you will need to at least reload it, otherwise apache will not apply your new configuration.

Comment: I would like to ask if it really is a good idea to dynamically create virtual hosts ... Usually such scheme is implemented using a single fallback host and rewriting rules evaluating the `HTTP_HOST` specified in incoming requests to tell different sites apart. Separate virtual hosts only make sense if you really implement different settings for the hosts that cannot be implemented in a dynamic manner.